# WCF and ObservableCollection<T> - Items are there, but empty?

Tags: c#, wcf, observablecollection, deserialization

I've got a method on a WCF service that returns an `ObservableCollection<T>`.  On the server side, before returning the result, I can see that the collection is populated with items and the items contain the data as expected.  On the client side, the collection is populated with the same number of items as on the server side, but all of the properties in each item are null (there are four strings and an enumerated type).

The type declaration for the items being returned is not decorated with the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes, as it resides in a shared .dll, and this has not been a problem for any other types in this assembly until now.  This particular type is decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute  Catching the response in Fiddler shows that the items still contain data before being deserialized.  Why would the values of the items' properties be lost in deserialization?

Comment: The (just wonderful) System Trace Viewer supports the System.Runtime.Serialization namespace, and I've found it useful sometimes to dig through diagnostic traces to pick up issues of this kind. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788183(v=bts.70).aspx for the relevant bits to add to the config. files - perhaps worth a shot?

Comment: I've used tracing before to get to the root of WCF problems, I should have thought of that.  I'll give it a whirl and see if it gets me anywhere.

Comment: I only discovered that System.Runtime.Serialization can spit output to the Trace Viewer logs - that saved me hours last week!

Comment: Yeah come to think of it I'm fairly sure I've only ever used it on System.ServiceModel, not with System.Runtime.Serialization...thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for kicks I decorated it with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes, and that did the trick.  It would appear that the enum didn't serialize/deserialize correctly.  Wish I had a better idea as to why, though.

Answer (score 0):

The type definitions in the dll should be marked serializable.

```
[Serializable()]        
public class TestSimpleObject  {...
```

Comment: The type is marked as Serializable as well, sorry I neglected to mention that in the question.